# i have a kafka datastream and wanted to do some calculations over the data using pyflink how can i do that?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

i wanted to calculate the average
power[x] = ch[x]*((60/5)*100/500)watts and
Energy Consumed[x] = ch[x]/500kwh

ch1-ch6 are the energy measurment values i will attach an image of what the data from kafka looks like,which will be on the terminal.
[Click to see the data(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgWrC.png)

Comment: Please show your code as text, not an image. Average of all the data in the topic? Or average per time window (minute, hour, day, etc)? The first isn't really possible since Kafka topics are considered infinitely long

Comment: yes average power of all data in the topic specific for each ch[x]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data from Kafka looks something like this:

```
{"gw_id": "sn001", "t": 1650270347, "ch1": 38, "ch2": 0, "ch3": 1, "ch4": 2, "ch5": 0, "ch6": 50}
```

I also assume that you are wanting to perform stateless computations on each of the `ch[x]` values, such as:

```
p[x] = ch[x]*((60/5)*100/500)
e[x] = ch[x]/500
```

By stateless, I mean that the output of the computation does not require previous values of ch[x].

There are 2 ways you can use Flink for your use case: use the [DataStream API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/overview/) or the [Table/SQL API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/overview/).  The [PyFlink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/overview/) docs also describe how to use these APIs in a Python environment.

The SQL approach is simpler - if you really need very custom processing or to process data in a non-relational way then you can consider using the DataStream API, but I'm only going to consider the SQL approach here.

NOTE: I have not attempted to run the below code, so there may well be syntax errors.

The first step is to define an input table using a connector that is appropriate for your data source, i.e. your Kafka stream. Make sure you use the [Kafka table connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/kafka/), not the DataStream one.

```
def create_input():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE input (
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'format' = 'json',
          <see docs for other props>
        )
    """
```

Now we define a function that will perform processing, here's an example that just returns the input and where we put that function in a separate module to make it easier to test:

```
# within module mymodule
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def my_func(i):
    return i



def create_some_function():
    return """
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION my_func AS 'mymodule.my_func' LANGUAGE PYTHON
    """
```

Now create your output table, for which we'll just use the [print connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/print/):

```
def create_output():
    return """
        CREATE TABLE output (
          `gw_id` VARCHAR,
          `ch1` BIGINT,
          `ch2` BIGINT,
          `ch3` BIGINT,
          `ch4` BIGINT,
          `ch5` BIGINT,
          `ch6` BIGINT,
          `ch1_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch2_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch3_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch4_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch5_mod` BIGINT,
          `ch6_mod` BIGINT,
          `t` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'print'
        )
    """
```

Now we can define out environment and then join the input and output tables:

```
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)

table_env.execute_sql(create_input())
table_env.execute_sql(create_some_function())
table_env.execute_sql(create_output())
table_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO output SELECT gw_id, t, ch1, my_func(ch1), ch2, my_func(ch2), ch3, my_func(ch3), ch4, my_func(ch4), ch5, my_func(ch5), ch6, my_func(ch6) FROM input").wait()
```

Functions can be defined to perform arbitrary processing of data, including accepting multiple parameters.  You can use Flink's windowing capabilities to perform stateful computation, such as averaging a series of values over a time window, see [here] under queries for more details (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/overview/)